# How do I reformat a python series (pandas.core.series.Series) of dates from yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 to m/d/yyyy?

Tags: python, pandas, date, format

I tried:
`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format="%m/%d/%Y")`
and I get this error:

> ValueError: time data '2012-12-27 00:00:00' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Thanks. One of the countless random things I tried ended up working:

df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime(date_format='%m/%d/%Y')